# Real bundles and equivariant bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is a Real vector bundle in the sense of Atiyah the same thing as an equivariant vector bundle with a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to ask whether an Atiyah’s Real vector bundle is the same as a real or a complex vector bundle in the category of $C_2$-spaces, the answer is no to both. (Note that a complex vector bundle is just a real vector bundle with the complex structure). A bundle $\pi: E\to X$ of $C_2$-spaces just means that the projection $\pi$ is equivariant w.r.t the actions specified on $E$ and on $X$. But then there are a lot of possibilities, which include the case of a plain real vector bundle (with trivial $C_2$ actions). Both a Real vector bundle in Atiyah’s sense and a complex vector bundle are real vector bundles with $C_2$ actions. They differ in how the complex numbers act on the fibers. For $x\in X$, we denote the $C_2$ action on $X$ as $\tau: x\mapsto \bar{x}$ and the real vector space isomorphism $\varphi_x:E_x\to E_{\bar{x}}$ of fibers. Then a Real vector bundle is defined so that the first commutative square below is satisfied and a complex vector bundle the second:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{C}\times E_x @>>> E_x\\
@V{J\times \varphi_x}VV @V{\varphi_x}VV\\
\mathbb{C}\times E_{\bar{x}} @>>> E_{\bar{x}} ,
\end{CD}

\begin{CD}
\mathbb{C}\times E_x @>>> E_x\\
@V{id\times \varphi_x}VV @V{\varphi_x}VV\\
\mathbb{C}\times E_{\bar{x}} @>>> E_{\bar{x}}
\end{CD}

Here, $J$ denotes the complex conjugation on complex numbers and all the horizontal maps are scalar multiplications by complex numbers. So for a Real vector bundle $\varphi_x(\lambda v_x)=\overline{\lambda} \varphi_x(v_x)$ and for a complex vector bundle $\varphi_x(\lambda v_x)=\lambda \varphi_x(v_x)$.

I have avoided calling either of them a “$C_2$-equivariant principal bundle” above because its definition is more involved, as one would have to think about how the structure groups interact with $C_2$ and the effect on the bundle. There's usually no need to worry about the exact definition of an equivariant $G$-bundle as laid out on nlab https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivariant+bundle#equivariant_bundles for general purposes. But from skimming through it, I would say that in terms of Definition 2.7, an Atiyah’s Real vector bundle would be a $C_2$-equivariant $(\mathbb{C},J)$-bundle over $(X,\tau)$ and a complex vector bundle a $C_2$-equivariant $(\mathbb{C},id)$-bundle over $(X,\tau)$.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. I was trying to understand the notion of equivariant Chern classes, for which there are seemingly different definitions (via the Borel construction or for Real bundles via le construction of B. Kahn). It seems that the word "equivariant" is used for different things.